# PHP NumberFormatter inverting commas and decimals

Tags: php, numberformatter

I'm using PHP's number formatter on a local server and while it does work, it's printing out US dollar amounts like this: 8.500,00 $ when I actually want it to look like this: $8,500.00.  Is there some parameter within the function that'll allow me to fix this problem or do I have to use something else?

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: Your locale may not be set to what you think.  How are you creating your `NumberFormatter` object?

Comment: @RocketHazmat You were right! I forgot to change the locale over to US instead of the previous setting (German), thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have the wrong locale set in your `NumberFormatter` object.  The format `$8,500.00` is the USA's format.  Make sure you've told `NumberFormatter` to use the correct locale.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$number = 1234.52;
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
$number = money_format('%#10.2n', $number);
```

**Update** oh, actually you said that you're using `NumberFormatter`. I just missed that. This should works fine as well:

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter( 'en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
$number = $formatter->format($number);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the `number_format` function make sure that you are using the decimal and comma in the right place in the function like the one below:

```
number_format ( $number , $decimals , '.' , ',' );
```

If you are using the NumberFormatter Class then I would recommend doing:

```
$number = 8500.00;
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
echo $fmt->format($number);
//Results in $8,500.00
```

Answer (score -2):

There is an function called [number_format](http://php.net/manual/de/function.number-format.php)

```
number_format ( $number , $decimals , $dec_separator , $thousands_separator)
```

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to change the locale on the function I was using, had it set to Denmark instead of the US.